# Office 365 integration with Asp.net web application (MVC Application)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365

We want to integrate Office 365 for viewing/updating documents online through web application in Asp.net.Is there any API provided by Office 365 to integrate this in application ?
and if any one can suggest the process for integrating Office 365 with web application will be helpfull.

Thanks !

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for you r requirement? I'm also trying to find a solution for the same requirement. But couldn't find any

Answer (score 5):

The new [Office 365 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview) is what you're looking for. It provides access to mails, calendars, contacts, users and groups, files, and folders in Office 365.

For your task the [file API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-file-tasks-client-library) should be the right one. With it you can access and manipulate Office and OneDrive for Business documents.

The links provided will show you how you can integrate it. Additionally there's an [Virtual Academy course](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/deep-dive-integrate-office-365-apis-in-your-web-apps?m=11478) on this topic. If you want to see some code, there are also some [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office%5Coffice365%5CHowTo/starter-projects-and-code-samples) available.